# In Firebase Table structure, how the retrieve the items from the subparent?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below i have attached the firebase table... here i have to list the child of date (chat2,chat1 from 1312206 followed by chat3,chat2,chat1 from 12122016).

Please anyone help how to query the data.Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to query for: what chat messages do you want to retrieve? And what's the condition that they have in common? Also: you've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to point to the correct node and then just attach a listener where you will get the callback.

```
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Chat chat = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
        // do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // do stuff when there is an error
    }
} 

DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference chatNode = database.child("chat_room").child("12122016").child("chat1")

chatNode.addValueEventListener(eventListener);
```

With this listener you'll be notified whenever there is an update on that node.

You can find more information in [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).